# Error al traer datos ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo una funcion que trae datos de otro archivo para poder llenar la informacion de unas graficas realizadas en amcharts. El problema que tengo es que solo la primera vez me trae los datos en la segunda ocacion que presiono el clic deja de traer la informacion que llena las graficas.
Este es mi script

```
<script>

    $('#Enviar').click(function(){
        var Fecha_ini=document.getElementById('minDate').value;
        var Fecha_fin=document.getElementById('maxDate').value;
        var Mercado=document.getElementById('selectmercado').value;
        var Zona=document.getElementById('nd_dropdown').value;

        var ruta="Fi="+Fecha_ini+"&Ff="+Fecha_fin+"&Mer="+Mercado+"&Zn="+Zona;

        $.ajax({
        data: ruta,
        url: '../funcs/consultas_graficas.php',
        type: 'POST',cache: false,
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            $('#componentes_pml').html("Loading...");
        },
        success: function(mensaje)
        {
            $('#componentes_pml').html(mensaje);
        }
        
        })  
    })
</script>
```

Asi inicializo el dom de la grafica

```
var chartDom = document.getElementById('componentes_pml');
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
var option;
```

Comment: Te sale algún error en la consola la segunda vez?

Comment: There is a chart instance already initialized on the dom.

Comment: como inicializas tu chart?

Comment: var chartDom = document.getElementById('componentes_pml');

var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);

var option;

Comment: eso pasa cuando una grafica ya tiene datos, cada vez que te traiga una respuesta, debes crear la grafica en el momento, no sobrescribirla

Comment: estoy bien verde en esto, como lo hago?